# JQuery: Dynamic page content and attaching button click

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have grid when click on pager link then html return from server side by ajax call and new grid html is getting append in a div. new html content has button which has class called `edit-user`.

so i wrote this code to attach jquery click with button which is adding in page dynamically.....but in my case it is not working.

```
$(function () {
    $('#gridContent').on('click','.edit-user', function () {
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
        $(tr).addClass('Editing');
        if ($(tr).find("td:nth-child(2)").hasClass('PadOn')) {
            $(tr).find("td:nth-child(2)").removeClass("PadOn");
            $(tr).find("td:nth-child(3)").removeClass("PadOn");
            $(tr).find("td:nth-child(4)").removeClass("PadOn");
            $(tr).find("td:nth-child(5)").removeClass("PadOn");

        }

        $(tr).find("td:nth-child(2)").addClass("PadOff");
        $(tr).find("td:nth-child(3)").addClass("PadOff");
        $(tr).find("td:nth-child(4)").addClass("PadOff");
        $(tr).find("td:nth-child(5)").addClass("PadOff");

        tr.find('.edit-mode, .display-mode').toggle();
        $(tr).find("input[id*='txtFirstName']").focus();
        return false;
    });
```

i am using jquery file version v1.10.2. looking for help and suggestion like where i made mistake for which new button has not getting attached with jquery button click event. thanks

Comment: Is the `#gridContent` also dynamic?

Comment: no...ajax content getting added in #gridContent .

Answer (score 1):

Try like following. Hope this will help.

```
 $('body').on('click','.edit-user', function () {
     //your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

issue sorted with this code

```
 $(document).on('click', '.edit-user', function () {
var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
        $(tr).addClass('Editing');
        if ($(tr).find("td:nth-child(2)").hasClass('PadOn')) {
            $(tr).find("td:nth-child(2)").removeClass("PadOn");
            $(tr).find("td:nth-child(3)").removeClass("PadOn");
            $(tr).find("td:nth-child(4)").removeClass("PadOn");
            $(tr).find("td:nth-child(5)").removeClass("PadOn");

        }

        $(tr).find("td:nth-child(2)").addClass("PadOff");
        $(tr).find("td:nth-child(3)").addClass("PadOff");
        $(tr).find("td:nth-child(4)").addClass("PadOff");
        $(tr).find("td:nth-child(5)").addClass("PadOff");

        tr.find('.edit-mode, .display-mode').toggle();
        $(tr).find("input[id*='txtFirstName']").focus();
        return false;
    });
```

thanks